# Need help retrieving a value

Tags: algorithm

This is an algorithm that takes as an input a value N (positive integer) and checks if the value can be expressed in the form of x^y. I can retrieve the base (x) but I'm not sure how I can get the exponent out without using another loop as to not to compromise the time complexity of it.

Example: N = 1024, X = 2, Y = 10

The value I need to retrieve is Y.

```
// Returns true if n can be written as x^y
bool isPower(unsigned int n)
{
    // Base case
    if (n <= 1) return true;

    // Try all numbers from 2 to sqrt(n) as base
    for (int x=2; x<=sqrt(n); x++)
    {
        unsigned  p = x;

        // Keep multiplying p with x while is smaller
        // than or equal to x
        while (p <= n)
        {
            p *= x;
            if (p == n)
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: The problem has a trivial solution: n is always n^1, so x=n and y=1 is always a solution. You probably mean _the smallest_ integer x for which n=x^y for some integer exponent y.

Comment: The algorithm runs so that the number N will be expressed with its lowest integer base and an exponent Y, so for example 16 will not be 4^2 (x^y), but 2^4. The base I know will be X but the exponent I can't figure out how to retrieve.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but the problem statement is a bit ambiguous. :-) You usually come up with an algorithm for a given well-defined problem. It's imporant that we know exactly what problem we're solving.

Comment: its clearly the logarithm your looking for. And the rule that log(a) base b equals  log(a) / log(b)

Answer (score 0):

You already got it. Y is just how many times you multiplied times x plus 1.

Edit: To be more clear in your inner loop put this:

```
    unsigned  p = x;
    unsigned  Y = 1;

    // Keep multiplying p with x while is smaller
    // than or equal to x
    while (p <= n)
    {
        p *= x;
        Y++;
        if (p == n)
            return true; // At this point Y is your Y, no need for another loop.
    }
```

Comment: He wants to find the exponent without the inner loop.

Comment: I want to find the exponent without adding another loop. You see after I have x I can just multiply x with itself until I get N and have a counter to find Y but that would add complexity to the algorithm.

Comment: @Joels Elf That would be the case if X won't be incremented.

Comment: @cheroz you don't need to do that because you already did it. In the loop where you multiply `p` times `x` keep a counter of how many times you do that multiplication. That counter is your Y. Here, I'll revise my answer with the *exact* code you would use.

Comment: Yes you are right, I placed Y outside the for loop when it was needed inside before the while, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could write a much more performant algorithm based on the following idea:

If you do a prime factorization then all the counts of the factors have to have a greates common divisor > 1. Because then you can group the prime factors into "gcd" groups, so this is also the exponent.

E.g. 2^6 * 3^4, gcd(4,6) = 2, which is also the exponent: (2^3*3^2)^2

Here is an example in Java:

```
// returns 0 if undefined and 1 if n can only be written as n^1
public static int getExponent(n) {
  if (n < 2)
    return 0;
  int min = 0;
  int prime = 2;
  while (prime <= sqrt(n)) {
    int count = 0;
    while (n % prime == 0) {
      count++;
      n /= prime;
    }
    if (count == 1)
      return 1;
    if (count > 1) {
      if (min == 0) {
        min = count;
      } else {
        min = greatestCommonDivisor(min, count);
        if (min == 1)
          return 1;
      }
      if (n == 1)
        return min;
    }
    prime = Primes.getNext(prime);
  }
  return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this loop instead:

```
// notice that it's decrementing 
for (int x=ceil(sqrt(n)); x>1; x--)
{
    // the actual base of the log is unimportant, just use the same one for both
    double p = log(n)/log(x);
    if(floor(p) == p) return true;
}
```

This will find the largest x (> 1, to exclude the trivial solution) such that p^x = n, which is equivalent to searching for the smallest p (again, < n). This works because log<sub>b</sub> a = log<sub>x</sub> a / log<sub>x</sub> b. You compute this division, then check whether you got an integer result.

There are more efficient ways to find p and x, but you asked specifically how to modify your existing algorithm to eliminate its inner loop.